# How to compare imploded values within $.each loop?

Tags: jquery

Below I'm checking each `<td>` that has value 'Thrs-1' and once found change the text to 'test'. This works fine as long as the value is not an array.

What if, the value is array storing comma separated values like this:`['Thrs-1','Sat-1','Sun-1']`

How do I run through each  to look for each for value stored in the $array?

```
 $("td").each(function() {
    if($(this).text().indexOf('Thrs-1') > -1)
    {
      $(this).text('test');
     }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.indexOf()` over array,

```
var arr = ['Thrs-1','Sat-1','Sun-1'];
$("td").each(function() {
    if(arr.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1) {
      $(this).text('test');
    }
});
```